# transient atributes of serializeable object are being deserialized as null

Tags: java, serialization, nullpointerexception, server, transient

So I have this class:

```
public class Message implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Location click;
    private String conection;
    private transient ArrayList<Location> allLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    private transient ArrayList<Snake> allSnakes = new ArrayList<Snake>();
    private transient ArrayList<Location> allObstacles = new ArrayList<Location>();
    private transient ArrayList<Location> allPowerups = new ArrayList<Location>();
    private boolean isConnecting;
    ........
}
```

And I need to send it through an ObjectStream, which works.
Unfortunately the arrayLists of that type aren't serializable, therefore I put the 'transient' keyword before it.
When deserializing it using .readObject() all the lists are null.
So my question is, how can the client/server send each other these lists?

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, how can the client/server send each other these lists?

Well, by marking those attributes as `transient`, you have implicitly *told* the `ObjectOutputStream` not to send them.

If you need to send them:

- remove the `transient` modifiers and change the `Location` and `Snake` classes to make then serializable, OR
- write custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods to serialize and deserialize those lists "by hand".

Making those classes serialization could be as simple as adding `implements Serializable` to the respective class declarations.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is Serializable.

Seems like your **Location** or **Snake** aren't. So just make them **serializable** and remove **transient**.

Answer (score 0):

Well transient means that you don't want that property to be serialized. But in your case you seem to have it wrong. ArrayList is serializable but for the whole list to serialize all its elements would be serialized as well. So make sure what ever you put in the List implements serializable.